# How do I use an EmailValidator in Spring.NET?

Tags: c#, validation, spring.net

I'm trying to use [validation in Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/validation.html) to validate that a string property of a class is a properly formatted e-mail address. I found the EmailValidator class ([source](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-net/blob/master/src/Spring/Spring.Core/Validation/Validators/EmailValidator.cs), [documentation](http://www.springframework.net/docs/1.3.2/api/net-2.0/html/topic9258.html)), but I'm unsure of the syntax needed to actually use it with my class.

I'm trying this:

```
<v:email id="validate.myClass.MailFrom" test="MailFrom">  
  <v:message id="myClass.MailFrom" providers="myClassProvider"/>  
</v:email>
```

but I get the error:

> The element 'group' in namespace 'http://www.springframework.net/validation' has invalid child element 'email' in namespace 'http://www.springframework.net/validation'. List of possible elements expected: 'validator, required, condition, regex, ref, collection, group, any, exclusive' in namespace 'http://www.springframework.net/validation'.

The same namespace that contains EmailValidator also contains ConditionValidator, RegularExpressionValidator, etc., which seem to correspond to allowed child elements. That doesn't seem to be the case for EmailValidator. What am I missing?

Comment: @Ramhound I understand the error. I don't know which of those elements will let me validate an e-mail address, so I don't know how to "fix" that code. I've added some clarification about my confusion about the allowed children to the question.

Comment: @Ramhound Look at the source link I posted for EmailValidator; it already uses regex internally.

Comment: I deleted my comments because it bugged me you didn't read the entire comments.  I suggested you use either `regex` OR `validator` child element which is exactly what `Marijn` suggested.  I shouldn't have to go to an external website to help you.  I figured out you had to use the `validator` child element based on the error message and the example code on the third-party website.

Comment: @Ramhound Telling me to use the `validator` element was unhelpful without also pointing out the `type` attribute, which is what I was missing. I did try several variants using the `validator` element first, but it didn't seem reasonable to post **everything** I'd tried. You complain about me not reading your comments and then say you shouldn't have to read the documentation I link to as part of my question. Uh, okay, dude...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```xml
<v:validator test="MailFrom"
             type="Spring.Validation.Validators.EmailValidator, Spring.Core">
   <v:message id="myClass.MailFrom" providers="myClassProvider"/>
</v:validator>
```

the email validator is a custom validator, which means you have to specify its type. In xml configuration, you use the validator tag as for your own custom validators. See http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/validation.html#d4e3643. I get your point about the other validator classes in the namespace having their own XML element. Maybe the email validator is considered too specific to warrant its own XML element?

Comment: Thank you so much! Specifying he `type` attribute was just what I needed.